# Filter on the count of a term reference field

Tags: views

I am trying to filter a view on the count of a term reference field.

Users submit a node of type **Write Up**. One of the fields is an entity reference of **Employee** and another is a term reference of **Reason**. One of the terms in the Reason vocabulary is Absence.

I am trying to create a view that shows all Employees with zero Write Ups of Absence.

My view is showing all Employees with a relationship to the Write Up. My thought was to add a filter of COUNT of Content: Reason = 0. However, I can only select the term *or* aggregate. I cannot seem to do both.